# Display images in iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, amazon-web-services

i want user upload their photos to Amazon S3  I use AWS SDK to upload pictures to the Amazon S3 service. While uploading photos with AWS SDK i want to  keep URL,path, of the photos in a database : i use this focntion to diplay image :
S3GetObjectRequest  *getObjectRequest  = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:nameImage withBucket:@"nameBucket"];

```
S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] getObject:getObjectRequest];

UIImage *tampon = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:getObjectResponse.body];
```

for one user taht have many images i have to now the name of each image to diplay image 
can u help me please??

Answer (score 0):

If your developing a Browser based application then your not likely to achieve your goal as I have yet to find a Browser on iOS that supports uploads from the browser to a server. It deals with Apples not allowing many things to directly communicate with the local storage.

On the flip side of that notion there are HTML5 based development solutions that do have API's tied into the devices hardware, such as phonegap and appmobi (which are one in the same) there is no PHP with it however, you will have to know javascript and something like jquery extensively to be able to communicate with your server or 3rd party system somewhere that accepts requests but in all, thats the basics to your problem, Apple just doesn't allow apps like browsers access to the storage directly I know the reason is actually a bit more elaborate but thats what it boils down to.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i'm developing application like instagram

Comment: be that as it may, if your using a browser in iOS thats not actually an app, the chances are you won't have the upload ability from a browser standalone. Even things like m.facebook.com don't have the upload option when your browser is iOS based. Its all because how Apple has things set up. So with that, thats all I am saying is your making an webapp for mobile browsers uploading the images will be difficult, Android also has its flukes straight from a browser